# git cloning Goldfish object corrupt error

Tags: android, git, github, android-kernel

I was trying to clone Android Goldfish kernel source code by using the following command,

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish
```

but as it needed to download around 900MB of data I thought what the heck and went through with this one,

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish --branch android-goldfish-3.4 --depth 1
```

this reduced the download size to around 120MB and the downloading was done but with an error during unpacking objects.

Later when I used `git status` I saw a large number of files were deleted and they were shown as if they not even added and committed. I, foolishly, added them and committed them as new commit named *'local commit'*.

```
git log --oneline
ca6ded2 Local Commit
2a51970 Merge branch 'android-3.4' into android-goldfish-3.4
c9cb2c8 UPSTREAM: netfilter: x_tables: fix unconditional helper
ac342b9 Merge branch 'android-3.4' into android-goldfish-3.4
```

Now after checking the files on remote, it became clear that the files which were shown deleted and which I committed are in the remote but not showing locally. So I tried to reset to previous commit. But these errors are shown:

```
git reset 2a51970
error: failed to read object b56d12bf5900c8f266132bc9b50dadfb092af10a at offset 26783674 from .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack
fatal: packed object b56d12bf5900c8f266132bc9b50dadfb092af10a (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack) is corrupt
```

fsck shows following:

```
git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack SHA1 checksum mismatch
error: index CRC mismatch for object b56d12bf5900c8f266132bc9b50dadfb092af10a from .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack at offset 26783674
error: cannot unpack b56d12bf5900c8f266132bc9b50dadfb092af10a from .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack at offset 26783674
error: index CRC mismatch for object 6149b476d9dffe06bcd1e3e3136bc335fd3dbf98 from .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack at offset 27883077
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
error: cannot unpack 6149b476d9dffe06bcd1e3e3136bc335fd3dbf98 from .git/objects/pack/pack-3ce58ac57f33a98f718e926caccca5ea5fa3a1fd.pack at offset 27883077
Checking objects: 100% (41134/41134), done.
```

**My question:**
Is there a way to fix this without initiating the cloning process again.
AND
Was the cloning done properly or I did something wrong there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a way to fix this!

For all object corruption error relating to git, I think the best, hassle free, thing to do will be to make use of *git-repair*.

**My procedure to Fix this (Ubuntu 16.04):**

1. Install git-repair

   sudo apt install git-repair
2. Goto the local git repo directory
3. Run git-repair

   git-repair

Thats it! All the corrupt objects were fixed(not going into technical details!) and the repo was in working condition.